# Word for a team from company 'A' working for company 'B ' at B's workplace? what this process can be called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, business-language

I think we can call it 'remote team' but is there any other more formal word for team and the process?

Comment: Sounds like a form of "outsourcing" which for some reason is carried out  internally. I think you need to add more context.

Comment: Could also be "consulting" or "contracting"...

Comment: Perhaps, "embedded."

Comment: yes it may be some form of outsourcing but lets say our company's client wants a team from our company to work at their office or location.. what should we call this process and team?

Comment: "On site" is a very common phrase.

Comment: There are a half-dozen different circumstances where the above general scenario might occur, with different terms to denote them.

Comment: @HotLicks: I agree. The question is unclear as to the context and relationships.

Comment: let's say if a software house sends their team to work on project at a factory.. what we will call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it a *contract* team or a *vendor* team.  These refer to the site's company's contractual agreement with the embedded team's employer.  You can also apply *on-site* or *embedded* as adjectives.

*Contract* makes more sense to me, in the *contractor* sense, but *vendor* is favored by a certain software behemoth in Redmond, WA, and I suppose I can see the logic in trying to insist that the outsourcing firms are selling (vending) services (their employees), rather than fulfilling a contract, because the way that behemoth has used "vendors" is to directly control the work of people (vendor's employees) without the HR overhead of anything except an hourly rate paid to the vendor (outsourcing) firm.  There's not really a fixed contract of limited duration or goals inherent in said behemoth paying money to the outsourcing firm... they're just paying for vendor employees like they'd pay for something from a vending machine.  You buy it as often as you'd like at a fixed price until you don't want it anymore.

Comment: This applies to me. I'm employed by company A working as a **contractor** on a company B site.

Answer (score 0):

The process is called **"lease"** and it has become very common.

> - lease (noun) "a contract by which one party conveys land, property, **services**, etc., to another for a specified time, usually in return for a periodic payment."
> - A lease is a contractual arrangement calling for the lessee (user) to pay the lessor (owner) for use of an asset.  Broadly put, a lease agreement is a contract between two parties, the lessor and the lessee. The lessor is the legal owner of the asset, the lessee obtains the right to use the asset in return for rental payments. [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lease#Sublease)

When the asset consists of services, you frequently have **a team from company A working at company B's workplace.**